# Can code be 'factored'? Is this the correct word?

Tags: word-usage

Within software development 'refactoring' is a common term.  I am reviewing a document containing the phrase "How much code change it requires will depend on how well the code is factored."

Is the use of the term factored valid here? I would have though it should be something like structured.

Comment: There's a reasonably comprehensive [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_(computer_science)) page on the subject. I don't know much about it, but the description there suggests that 'structured' isn't quite the same thing. But you may disagree - for future reference, it's a good idea to describe your prior research and explain why it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from a software field, i would certainly say the word *Code Factoring* is quite common. Not a day goes by without me hearing it.

It refers to the Structure, readability and the Complexity of the program. Its usage in the sentence seem to make sense , though personally i have never come across such a usage.

If people are not already using this,  may be they can start now! It is out there in the pockets somewhere. So, don't be surprised to hear it again.

Comment: I’ve never heard of it.

Comment: @tchrist , Yes, me neither. But i will probably start using it.